# Was Tom Flannery's disease retconned in later editions of Callahan's Crosstime Saloon?

Tags: retcon, spider-robinson, callahans-crosstime-saloon

I was reading through *Callahan's Crosstime Saloon* by Spider Robinson, and I came across [this passage](https://books.google.com/books?id=PHAbZxdIh2EC&lpg=PA157&dq=Callahan's%20Crosstime%20Saloon&pg=PA157):

> Tom Flannery's there now, frozen like a popsicle, waitin' for them to invent a cure for AIDS; he tol' me about it.

In this same story,

> Rebecca explains that she was born in 1741, making her 232 years old,

which means that the current year is 1973-1974 (I think other stories indicate that it's 1974, but the dialogue seems to indicate 1973, so maybe they are not in chronological order), but AIDS was rare (if present at all) in the US in the 70s, and [wasn't even named AIDS until 1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_AIDS#1981:_From_GRID_to_AIDS).

Given that the book came out in 1977, I am assuming that this must have been a retro-fit in one of the later editions. Was this a retcon by Spider Robinson, or were people actually aware of AIDS and calling it that in the 70s? If it is a retcon - what did it replace, and has Spider Robinson ever revealed why he made this change?

Comment: It was leukemia. Why Robinson changed it I do not know.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this review](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Callahans-Crosstime-Saloon-Spider-Robinson/dp/0812572270) on Amazon, the original wording was

> "waiting for a cure **for Leukemia**".

Per Amazon

> *Second, there's an "update" in "A Voice is Heard in Ramah..." that
>   makes no sense. Tom Flannery is a character who'd been given 9 months
>   to live when he first walked in to Callahan's. **In "A Voice..." it's
>   mentioned that he has some of his skin cells preserved at a place in
>   Manhattan where they're holding cells for the future when cloning
>   humans is possible. It states that he's frozen there "waitin' for 'em
>   to invent a cure for AIDS". Now, these stories obviously take place in
>   the 1970s, and the original text in my paperback says that he was
>   waiting for a cure for leukemia.** HIV and AIDS weren't recognized by
>   the CDC until 1981, the folks at Callahan's wouldn't have known about
>   it. Also, HIV is a disease you catch, not a genetic disorder. Someone
>   with AIDS could be cloned without any risk of having the disease.*

And backed up [here](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/145)

Comment: I'm torn about this answer. On the one hand, I have no reason to doubt that it changed from leukemia. On the other, an amazon review does not seem like a particularly authoritative source, nor does it address why this nonsensical change was made (though there's a comment on it that speculates that the reason was that leukemia was much more of a death sentence in the 70s and it was "translated" for newer audiences). I've upvoted but I think I'll hold off on accepting - hopefully that does not offend.

Comment: @Paul - Not at all. I've seen several [sources](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/145) indicating the change but none from any source dramatically more authoritative than this amazon review and none that explain the change.

Comment: @Paul - My personal advice is to not accept my answer. It only covers half of what you've asked. That doesn't mean that you can't upvote it though. As the FAQ says, partial answers need love too...

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer:

Yes, it was retconned; no clue as to why.

Here's a scan of my June 1984 eighth printing of the Ace paperback edition where the passage read as:

> Tom Flannery's there now, frozen like a popsicle, waitin' for 'em to invent a cure for leukemia; he tol' me about it."

[image: Scan of the relevant page from the books with an arrow pointing to the section quoted above]